# tkinter scrollbar attached to listbox in a grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

Been staring at this code for so long, I can't see what is wrong with it.
When I run it, I get the `listbox` and <kbd>OK</kbd> button as I expect, but the `scrollbar` appears in the middle
of the `listbox` widget and  doesn't actually scroll.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def confirm_selection():
  selection = sensor_listbox.get(sensor_listbox.curselection())
  print("Selected:", selection)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("USGS Data To Download From Glovis Scenelist")
w = 730 # width for the Tk root
h = 500 # height for the Tk root
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

#create listbox and scrollbar
sensor_listbox = tk.Listbox(root, height=3,width=20)
sensor_listbox.grid(row=0, column=2)#,columnspan=3)

sensor_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root)
sensor_scroll.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='ns')
sensor_scroll.configure(command=sensor_listbox.yview)
sensor_listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=sensor_scroll.set)


# Add items to the listbox
sensor_list = ["Sentinel-2", "Sentinel-1", "Landsat-8/9","Landsat-7","Landsat-4/5","ASTER (SWIR                  On)","ASTER (SWIR Off)"]
for item in sensor_list:
   sensor_listbox.insert("end",item)

sensor_listbox.select_set(4)

button = tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=confirm_selection)
button.grid(row=3, column=2)#,columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting the `listbox` to have a `scrollbar` attached on the right side.

Comment: You put both the listbox and scrollbar in same cell, row 0 column 2.

Comment: Put the scrollbar at row 0 column 3.  And the scrollbar works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
sensor_scroll.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='ns')
```

to:

```
sensor_scroll.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='ne')
```